# Preserve javascript console line number output in dev tools browser console after overriding the console object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, console.log

I have a javascript function that overrides the `console.log` function which forwards the args to another destination. I still want the log to be output in the browser console unchanged. However, the original line number where the console.log was originally called is not showing and instead the line number is always the point where `apply` is called.

Is it possible to preserve the original line number where the console is called and what would be the best approach to do that?

The app I am building is VueJS so I've put together an example as a VueJS Component below. This example can be saved as `App.vue` and tested using `vue serve`. When the 'Test Log' button is clicked you will see the log in the view and also in the dev tools you will see the log output in the console. The issue is that the line number is always this line `o_log.apply(console, arguments)` and I really need it to be this line `console.log('in testLog()')` (i.e. the line number where console log was originally called).

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{name}}</h1>
    <button @click="testLog">Test Log</button>
    <hr/>
    <p v-for="(log, i) in logs" :key="i" :style="{background: log.color}" >{{log.message}}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      name: 'Console Log Prototype',
      logs: [],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    testLog() {
      console.log('in testLog()')
    }
  },
  created() {
    let self = this;
    var o_log = console.log
    function customLog(msg) {
      var entry = {color: 'pink', message: msg}
      self.logs.push(entry)
      o_log.apply(console, arguments)
    }
    console.log = customLog;
  }
}
</script>
```